# Is there a good chart, comparing the various Russian engines proposed for Soyuz (Booster) upgrades?

Tags: engines, booster, soyuz-launcher

There are so many proposed Soyuz booster upgrades, I cannot keep them straight.

I was wondering if there is a good comparison chart between the various proposed upgrades, including engine information.

For example: The traditional Soyuz, used to launch manned and unmanned flights to the ISS.
The Soyuz-ST used to launch satellites out of Korou by ESA.
The Soyuz 2-1-V just launched.

There are a variety of proposed Soyuz 2 variants proposed as well.

Comment: Would [this one](http://www.spacelaunchreport.com/soyuz.html) do? Feel free to reuse it for an answer, if that meets your criteria. It looks updated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on a comment, there is a table at [Space Launch Report](http://www.spacelaunchreport.com/soyuz.html).